# Deploy apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I have a really simple app script and previously it was installed as a menu item in my Google Sheets. Each time I opened a Google Sheet, I could see the menu I had created.
I have somehow deleted it, and now I am really struggling publishing my app script.

I can copy the code, review permissions etc and run manually, but I use many new sheets a day, so really need it installed.

Question 1. 
To have this custom menu for all my sheets, do I need to login in at `script.google.com` and then click Publish > Deploy as Add-On?

Question 2. 
Following the Add-on link is all the same, but I am very stuck with `Upload Updated Package`. 
For my really simple app, is there a simple way I can create this zip package? It seems I need to set-up an API and all sorts of things. Very full on, for a tiny little app I want to run personally.

Is there another way?